# Showing that $\tau(2^n − 1)  \ge \tau (n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Show that $\tau (2^n − 1) \ge \tau (n)$, where $\tau (n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$ including $n$ itself and $1$.  I just can not seem to figure this one out any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Victor: Please don't create tags for no reason.

Comment: @Aryabhata - Just try to be more specific.

Comment: @Victor: The question wasn't about $\tau$ being a multiplicative function. You just can't tag it with some property of $\tau$ like that. By the same logic, one can tag it as unbounded-function. Also, tags are supposed to be at the right level of specificity. Being too specific or too broad is not recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all positive integers $k$ and $\ell$,
$$2^{k\ell}-1=(2^k-1)(2^{k(\ell-1)}+2^{k(\ell-2)}+\cdots+2^k+1).$$
So, if $k$ divides $n$, $2^k-1$ divides $2^n-1$.  Therefore, $2^n-1$ must have at least as many divisors as $n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot David that was really helpful.  I knew that use of the geometric progression was important in figuring this out, but just could not see this simple result.